# Making Buddypress name field not required

Tags: wordpress, registration, buddypress

I'm using Buddypress on WordPress with latest version.

Buddypress is showing name field as required. I inspected the code and it says there, area-field required.

How can I make it optional or not required?

I have attached the image of code. I don't want to edit the plugin file.

Kind Regards

I tried jquery code to make it not required but that didn't work.

Comment: Buddypress forums seem to have a few suggestions. Like this one: https://buddypress.org/support/topic/hide-required-buddypress-name-field/